# When put the thread to sleep state through `nanosleep` for a short duration, say, 100us, how the OS achieve it?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, sleep

When puts the thread to sleep state through `nanosleep`  for **a short duration**, say, **1us**,how the OS achieve it?

**Busy waiting or suspend the thread and wait for the interupt produced by RTC?**

I would be thankful for any hint on this question.

Comment: It suspends the thread so other threads can run while the thread is sleeping.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1392423/how-does-a-computer-sleep-wait-without-using-all-of-its-processing-power/1393296#1393296

Comment: https://www.tombarbette.be/understanding-sleeping-mechanism-in-linux-kernel/

Comment: @Barmar Glad to see you again! **For just 1us?** I guess the duration costed by context switches may be longer then busy waitting.

Comment: @KamilCuk, **for 1us**?! I guess setting up timer will cost more.

Comment: `I guess setting up timer will cost more` Maybe, maybe not, you can't guess the speed of client machine. Why would a small duration be handled specially? Nanosleep sleeps the thread for the time __not less__ then specified, not exactly specified.

Comment: @KamilCuk, seems like lack of physics at the school :) error margin of the measuring tool is higher when your measured value is close to a resolution of the tool.